# Sum from $k=1$ to $n$ of $k^3$

Tags: real-analysis, induction

$$\sum_{k=1}^n k^3 = \left(\frac{1}{2}n(n+1) \right)^2$$

I want to prove this using induction. I start with $(\frac{n}{2}(n+1))^2 + (n+1)^3$ and rewrite $(n+1)^3$ as $(n+1)(n+1)^2$, then factor out an $(n+1)^2$ from the expression:

$(n+1)^2((\frac{n}{2})^2 + (n+1))$

I'm confused where to go from here though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(n+1)^2((\frac{n}{2})^2 + (n+1))=(n+1)^2\frac{n^2+4n+4}{4}=(n+1)^2\frac{(n+2)^2}{2^2}= \left(\frac{1}{2}(n+1)((n+1)+1) \right)^2$

Comment: perfect, thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

Observe that

$$ \left( \left( \tfrac{n}{2} \right)^2 + n + 1 \right) = \left( \frac{n^2 + 4n + 4}{4} \right) = \left( \frac{n+2}{2} \right)^2$$

Comment: for some reason, the latex isnt working. also, L is awesome!

Comment: @furashu It's working now. Agreed! ;)